# Freetype with Ubuntu patches in Gentoo overlays

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, overlay, freetype, gentoo

There has been bobrik-cleartype overlay for Gentoo which contained freetype, libXft, etc, packages with patches from Ubuntu (adding USE +ubuntu). Then it has been absorbed by devnull overlay.

Now that devnull is dead, I wonder if up-to-date packages with these patches are available in some other overlay, anyone using them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the latest version of gentoo doesnot need the ubuntu patch.

so just use the portage:)

Comment: By 'does not need' do you mean it already has the same functionality as in the patch? Is it on by default? (since there is no +ubuntu USE anymore).

Comment: I have compared the ubuntu and gentoo, arch rendering effect.
arch + ubuntu patch = ubuntu = gentoo :)

Comment: you can try install ubuntu & arch in virtualbox to compare the effect.In my case, they are the same.:)